# Reading Transformer result line by line (Java)

Tags: java, xml, string, line

I'm using Transformer to prettify and to insert indentation to an XML which is originally one big line.
Here is my code:

```
BufferedWriter br = null;
Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(inputSR);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(); 
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
```

How can I write the `xmlOutput` to a file, **line by line** (without loading the whole string to the memory)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a StringWriter, use a FileOutputStream:

```
StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"))
```

This will write incrementally to the file. It won't necessarily write line-by-line (lines don't mean much in XML), but I can't see why you would want that.

Comment: the purpose was to modify certain tags before writing it to disk.

Comment: You would probably be better off using a SAXResult. The result tree will then be sent event-by-event to your ContentHandler. If you want to modify the post-serialization result stream, you could implement a Writer and intercept the write() calls, but you'll have to do your own buffering to avoid the text your are looking for spanning multiple calls on methods such as write().